# Spring dependency injection issue during deployment

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, dependency-injection, autowired

I'm starting a Primefaces/Spring/Hibernate project and I'm still learning how to handle those components properly. But at this right moment, I'm facing a problem related to spring dependency injection that is freaking me out. I've been look for an answer for two days over the web and couldn't find what is wrong with my code. I've tried both approaches to autowire (@Autowire ans @Inject). Could someone take a look at my code and check what's going wrong ? My code is below.

Here is the error log during deployment:

```
21:29:14,419 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] Bean 'entityManagerFactory' of type [class org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
21:29:14,441 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@68a0d2d2: defining beans [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,mvcContentNegotiationManager,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver#0,pessoaBean,pessoaServiceImpl,pessoaDAOImpl,org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver#0,dataSource,entityManagerFactory,transactionManager,org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor#0,org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
21:29:14,504 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping] Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler#0'
21:29:14,716 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@68a0d2d2: defining beans [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,mvcContentNegotiationManager,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver#0,pessoaBean,pessoaServiceImpl,pessoaDAOImpl,org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver#0,dataSource,entityManagerFactory,transactionManager,org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor#0,org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
21:29:14,739 INFO  [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean] Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'CentralSisatPersistenceUnit'
21:29:14,741 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pessoaServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private br.com.centralemprestimos.sisat.persistence.PessoaDAO br.com.centralemprestimos.sisat.service.PessoaServiceImpl.pessoaDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [br.com.centralemprestimos.sisat.persistence.PessoaDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289) [spring-beans-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1146) [spring-beans-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519) [spring-beans-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458) [spring-beans-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296) [spring-beans-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223) [spring-beans-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293) [spring-beans-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) [spring-beans-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628) [spring-beans-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932) [spring-context-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479) [spring-context-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410) [spring-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) [spring-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112) [spring-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private br.com.centralemprestimos.sisat.persistence.PessoaDAO br.com.centralemprestimos.sisat.service.PessoaServiceImpl.pessoaDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [br.com.centralemprestimos.sisat.persistence.PessoaDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:517) [spring-beans-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87) [spring-beans-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:286) [spring-beans-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
... 21 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [br.com.centralemprestimos.sisat.persistence.PessoaDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:988) [spring-beans-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858) [spring-beans-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770) [spring-beans-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:489) [spring-beans-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
... 23 more

21:29:14,771 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/Central]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pessoaServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private br.com.centralemprestimos.sisat.persistence.PessoaDAO br.com.centralemprestimos.sisat.service.PessoaServiceImpl.pessoaDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [br.com.centralemprestimos.sisat.persistence.PessoaDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289) [spring-beans-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1146) [spring-beans-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519) [spring-beans-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458) [spring-beans-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296) [spring-beans-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223) [spring-beans-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293) [spring-beans-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) [spring-beans-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628) [spring-beans-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932) [spring-context-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479) [spring-context-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410) [spring-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) [spring-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112) [spring-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private br.com.centralemprestimos.sisat.persistence.PessoaDAO br.com.centralemprestimos.sisat.service.PessoaServiceImpl.pessoaDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [br.com.centralemprestimos.sisat.persistence.PessoaDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:517) [spring-beans-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87) [spring-beans-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:286) [spring-beans-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
... 21 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [br.com.centralemprestimos.sisat.persistence.PessoaDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:988) [spring-beans-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858) [spring-beans-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770) [spring-beans-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
at ...
```

web.xml

```
<display-name>Central</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.UPLOADER</param-name>
    <param-value>auto</param-value>
</context-param>
<filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>uploadDirectory</param-name>
        <param-value>c:/primefaces/</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">

<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>                          
<context:annotation-config/>
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<context:component-scan base-package="  br.com.centralemprestimos.sisat.mbean,
                                        br.com.centralemprestimos.sisat.service,
                                        br.com.mobinn.fmwk.persistence,
                                        br.com.centralemprestimos.sisat.persistence,
                                        br.com.centralemprestimos.sisat.service,
                                        br.com.mobinn.fmwk.service"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>


<!-- Data Source Declaration -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/central" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="root" />
</bean>


<!-- Entity Manager Factory Declaration -->
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="CentralSisatPersistenceUnit" />
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml" /> 
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>br.com.mobinn.fmwk.persistence</value>
            <value>br.com.centralemprestimos.sisat.entity</value>
            <value>br.com.centralemprestimos.sisat.persistence</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="database" value="MYSQL" />
        </bean>
    </property>
 </bean>    

 <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
 </bean>

 <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
 <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

 <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="false"/>

</beans>
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="CentralSisatPersistenceUnit">

    <class>br.com.centralemprestimos.sisat.entity.Telefone</class>
    <class>br.com.centralemprestimos.sisat.entity.Pessoa</class>

    <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="MySQL"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>

        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="3"/>
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform" />
        <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true"/>
        <property name="show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>  
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="DEBUG"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

PessoaDAOImpl.java

```
package br.com.centralemprestimos.sisat.persistence;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import br.com.centralemprestimos.sisat.entity.Pessoa;
import br.com.mobinn.fmwk.persistence.GenericDAOImpl;

@Repository
public class PessoaDAOImpl extends GenericDAOImpl<Pessoa>{

@PersistenceContext(name="CentralSisatPersistenceUnit")
protected EntityManager entityManager;

public void doSomething() {
    System.out.println("Bean was correctly injected!");
}

}
```

PessoaBean.java

```
package br.com.centralemprestimos.sisat.mbean;

import java.io.Serializable; ...

import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.jboss.logging.Logger;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import br.com.centralemprestimos.sisat.entity.Pessoa;
import br.com.centralemprestimos.sisat.entity.Telefone;
import br.com.centralemprestimos.sisat.service.PessoaService;
import br.com.centralemprestimos.sisat.util.FacesUIHelper;
import br.com.mobinn.fmwk.exception.BusinessException;

@Component
@Scope("request")
public class PessoaBean implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public Logger logger =             Logger.getLogger("br.com.centralemprestimos.sisat.mbean.PessoaBean");

@Inject
private PessoaService pessoaService;
```

PessoaServiceImpl.java

```
package br.com.centralemprestimos.sisat.service;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import br.com.centralemprestimos.sisat.entity.Pessoa;
import br.com.centralemprestimos.sisat.persistence.PessoaDAO;
import br.com.mobinn.fmwk.service.GenericServiceImpl;

@Service
public class PessoaServiceImpl extends GenericServiceImpl<Pessoa> implements Serializable, PessoaService {

@Inject
private PessoaDAO pessoaDAO;

public PessoaDAO getPessoaDAO() {
    return pessoaDAO;
}

public void setPessoaDAO(PessoaDAO pessoaDAO) {
    this.pessoaDAO = pessoaDAO;
}

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `PessoaDAO` an interface?

Comment: Yep, it is. Got it!! Here it's the problem. I forgot to implement DAO interface... What silly error! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring is attempting to autowire the `PessoaDAO` bean in the `PessoaServiceImpl` class (which by default is done by type), however there are no beans of that type.

You can see this in the stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [br.com.centralemprestimos.sisat.persistence.PessoaDAO]
```

I assume that `PessoaDAO` is an interface and you meant `PessoaDAOImpl` to implement it.  If you make this class implement the interface, Spring should autowire the bean by the type.

```
@Repository
public class PessoaDAOImpl extends GenericDAOImpl<Pessoa> implements PessoaDAO{

}
```

Comment: Yep! You're right... Gorgot to implement DAO interface. Dumb error!