# Spring @Inject not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-elasticsearch

I've recently upgraded a project from Spring 4.3.1 to 4.3.4 and what used to work fine, now just won't work for me.

I use JPA, which holds a series of repository classes:

```
 /**
 * Spring Data JPA repository for the DrugQualityCategory entity.
 */

public interface DrugQualityCategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<DrugQualityCategory,Long> {

    @Query(value = "Select a from DrugQualityCategory a where a.oldId = ?1")
    DrugQualityCategory findOneByOldId(Integer oldId);

}
```

We also use ElasticSearch for the search engine, which creates a series of SearchRepositories like this:

```
  /**
 * Spring Data ElasticSearch repository for the Publication entity.
 */
public interface DrugQualityCategorySearchRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Publication, Long> {
}
```

One of the issues with ES is that it needs to regularly update its indices, so for this we built a test where it injects all repositories and rebuilds them from the JPA repository, looking like this when we inject the repos:

```
 @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
  @WebAppConfiguration
  @Transactional
  @ActiveProfiles("syncElasticsearch")
    public class SyncMysqlElasticSearch {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Inject DrugQualityCategoryRepository drugQualityCategoryRepository;
    @Inject TechniqueRepository techniqueRepository;
    @Inject TradeDrugRepository tradeDrugRepository;
    @Inject SurveyDataRepository surveyDataRepository;
    @Inject RQAAQualityRepository rqaaQualityRepository;
```

And then we fill the ES instances:

```
drugQualityCategorySearchRepository.save(drugQualityCategoryRepository.findAll());
formulationSearchRepository.save(formulationRepository.findAll());
innDrugSearchRepository.save(innDrugRepository.findAll());
locationSearchRepository.save(locationRepository.findAll());
manufacturerSearchRepository.save(manufacturerRepository.findAll());
```

Now, the issue I have is that when I try to start the test, I keep on getting:

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
Error creating bean with name [class name] Unsatisfied dependency expressed
through field [field name] nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:
No qualifying bean of type [class name] available: expected at least
1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
```

I've checked several questions here like  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41745591/spring-dependency-injection-not-working-spring-4)  and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21505301/spring-dependency-injection-issue-during-deployment), had a quick browse on the Spring docs, but couldn't find anything relevant

I've obviously tried all the `@Autowired`, `@Component` and `@Repository` tags in different places, to no positive result

Comment: how do you setup your context for testing?

Comment: Hi Jan, I'm not sure I know what you mean by context here, I have a config yml file that sets the connection parameters for both ES and JPA, other than that, I only have the annotations that are in the code extracts in the original question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to annotate your test class with a @ContextConfiguration annotation which points to the relevant @Configuration class which scans and registers all these beans you're trying to inject.

See the java docs for @WebAppConfiguration:

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/web/WebAppConfiguration.html

> Note that @WebAppConfiguration must be used in conjunction with @ContextConfiguration, either within a single test class or within a test class hierarchy.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, I've been trying with this for the last hour, still can't make it to work.  I've tried just adding the annotation for context, it won't take my main class as parameter, it says it doesn't exist, it wont take a classpath*: as parameter either.
I've tried adding the Configuration tag to the main class, no luck with that, also made most combinations with Repository tags, etc...  Am I missing something?

Comment: @Steven You using xml or Java conig or spring boot?

Comment: Java config with Spring boot, I think I might be on to something, I just annotated with ContextConfiguration(classes = DrugQualityDataManagerApp.class) and now it's giving me what I believe to be an unrelated error

Comment: @Steven Ok cool. You could try using 'SpringBootTest' annotation instead of 'ContextConfiguration'. Spring boot can magically wire in the relevant configuration then (usually). What is your new error?

Comment: Awesome, thank you for that, right now I'm getting other properties that aren't binding, error starts as Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException and goes on forever, but I think and hope I've got this

Comment: @Steven Ok brilliant, best of luck. :)